# Maven - how to package jdbc driver to a particular folder

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, mariadb, driver

I need to package jdbc driver for maria db into a particular folder using maven. For this we don't want to download and keep a copy of the file in the project. Instead it should fetch from the maven repository(remote/local or any) and should keep the file to the folder in which we need.
Is there any way to download and keep the file to a particular folder when we build it.

something like bellow

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nokia.patches.org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client-01</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10</version>
    <folder>lib/ext</folder>
</dependency>
```

Note: This driver jar file even available in the class path.

Any help would really appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basic maven feature

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                            <version>${jacoco.agent.version}</version>
                            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
                            <outputDirectory>requiredFolderName</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>jacoco-agent.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```